# Connect RFCOMM profile using BlueZ 5

Tags: qt, bluetooth, bluez, pebble-watch, sailfish-os

I am trying to port code connecting Pebble Watch serial port to BlueZ 5.

The original (BlueZ 4) code used `QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol)` to establish RFCOMM connection on channel 1.

What I understand, in BlueZ 5 I need to create a Profile, set it to client mode, configure channel and register it to BlueZ DBus daemon. Then i use this profile to connect to Bluetooth device and it should give me a file-descriptor.

The thing is, that Pebble Watch does not advertise `0x1101` SerialPort profile UUID.

```
"Pebble Time 6C96"
("00000000-DECA-FADE-DECA-DEAFDECACAFF", "00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
```

so, when I try to connect it, I get `"br-connection-profile-unavailable"` error.

Is there some way to force connecting to SerialPort profile?